# При записи в БД русские символы записываются как #####

Tags: delphi, база-данных

Файл разметки выглядит вот так:

```
[Weather]
Filetype=VARYING
Delimiter="
Separator=,
CharSet=ascii
Field1=id,Char,20,00,00

Field2=username,Char,20,00,20

Field3=city,Char,20,00,40

Field4=time,Char,05,00,60

Field5=count,Char,10,00,65
```

Подключаюсь к БД я вот так:

```
with Table1 do begin
  TableType := ttASCII;
  DatabaseName := exePath;
  TableName := 'Weather';
  Open;
end;
```

Записываю данные вот так:

```
  Table1.Insert;
  Table1.FieldByName('id').AsAnsiString := '1234567';
  Table1.FieldByName('username').AsAnsiString := 'aaaaa';
  Table1.FieldByName('city').AsAnsiString := 'Москва';
  Table1.FieldByName('time').AsAnsiString := '4';
  Table1.FieldByName('count').AsAnsiString := '0';
  Table1.Post;
```

А результат выглядит вот так:

```
"1234567","aaaaa","######","4","0"
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Так может использовать не ASCII, в котором не регламентировано расположение национальных символов, а (если мы уж продолжаем рассматривать однобайтные) Windows-1251, например?

Comment: _в чём может быть проблема?_ Проблема в кодировке. 100%

Comment: @kami как использовать что-то другое? Для текстового файла как БД TableType есть только как ttASCII

Comment: @kot-da-vinci понятное дело, что в кодировке, а что делать то? 
Да, наверное я некорректно вопрос в конце задал

Comment: Но вы же в разметке указываете CharSet? Значит, надо посмотреть допустимые значения и выбрать нужное.

Comment: @kami использование любого другого значения charset ведёт к 'Unknown internal operating system error.' Пробовал utf8, cp1251... Также попробовал поменять кодировку самого текстового файла в соответствие к charset. Работает только при charset=ascii

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/822016/4908529

Comment: @kami спасибо тебе огромное, charset=ANSIINTL помогло

Comment: @St-dimka - возьмите на себя труд - оформите как ответ, указав допустимые значения charset. Я надеюсь, у вас есть файл справки, указанный в приведенном по ссылке ответе?

Answer (score 4):

Помогло использование ANSIINTL в качестве кодировки в файле разметки (*.sch), сейчас его заголовок выглядит так:

```
[Weather]
Filetype=VARYING
Delimiter="
Separator=,
CharSet=ANSIINTL
```

Подробное описание содержания разметки *.sch находится в файле справки bde32.hlp в теме "Binding external schema to text tables".
Под заголовком "Language drivers" описаны возможные значения Charset.

[image: Несколько возможных значений Charset, которые могут пригодиться]

Спасибо @kami за помощь, источник: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819482/what-standard-does-bde-use-for-sch-schema-files/822016#822016

Comment: Спасибо. Странно, что самого ANSIINTL нет...

Comment: Есть. Он в самом низу, но для парадокс бд, я решил не включать в список
Да, странновато тогда получается, но не переделывать ведь теперь весь ответ

Comment: @St-dimka не надо переделывать весь ответ, внесите в ваш ответ правку с комментарием по поводу ANSIINTL.